# Git: Remove all commits from pull request

Tags: git

I have a Pull Request where I've added commits. However, I want to remove all commits from that PR and start from scratch. Where can I add my commits again?

I used `git rebase` but I don't have much of an idea about how to use it.

Please guide me.

Comment: If you don't need any commits then you can `close the PR`,  create a new branch | commits | PR. Does it mendatory to create the PR from `same branch` you created now?

Comment: Yes, I've to use the same PR.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove N commits then you can use `--hard reset HEAD~N`.

```
$ git branch -b backup               # backup the branch for safety

$ git log                            # count how many commits you want to remove

$ git reset --hard HEAD~3            # Let, you want to remove 3 commits here   
$ git push -f origin HEAD            # force (-f) push to remote as you rewrite the history
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what if I need to change some specific commit at the mid?

Comment: interactive rebase (`rebase -i`) better in that case.